# Assume unchanged for new items

Tags: git

So, `git update-index --assume-unchaged` allows me to mark something as unchanged, which is great (especially if I'm adding log lines which shouldn't be committed). Unfortunately, I have some files which I've added to a project and there is no reason whatsoever that the rest of the world should need (or even want) to have them. But because they're there, I can't do `git add .`, and they show up every time I use `git status`.

Is there an equivalent to `git update-index --assume-unchaged` for new files and directories?

Comment: Don't you want to use [.gitignore](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files)?

Comment: No, gitignore is versioned (though I suppose I could mark .gitignore as unchanged, I'll bashfully admit that I hadn't thought of that), and I'm also interested in learning whether there is an equivalent way to `update-index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `.gitignore` can do this task.

But if you don't want, you can use `.git/info/exclude` file. The syntax of `exclude` file is same with `.gitignore`. The difference is `.gitignore` can be versioned while `exclude` cannot and it only affects your own files.